# How do I add a percentage to a value in LINQ?

Tags: asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

How do I add a percentage of a value to itself using LINQ? For example, say the price is £10. Adding 6% of that price to itself gives £10.60. My code would look something like this, although I want to perform this calculation within an `insert` statement.

```
aPrice + aPercentage = bPrice
```

Comment: Do you mean LINQ, or LINQ to SQL?

Comment: LINQ to SQL, i will be getting the percentage and the price out of the DB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the usual way of doing this is to do

```
newPrice = price *1.06M;
```

If you have a value as a percentage between 0 and 100 then do the following:

```
Decimal newPrice *= 1.0M + (PercentageVakye / 100M);
```

NOTE: always use Decimal not Double when working with Prices.

Comment: morning, I am passing the percentage in via the DB as it is stored as a setting. Thus it is stored as 6.00.

How would i have it work it out this way?